# GSpread CellFormat foregroundColor

Tags: python, python-2.7, colors, google-sheets-api, gspread

I am trying to colour my header in Google Sheets purple, however GSpread textFormat doesn't seem to bring back the correct colour.

I have looked through the GSpread documentation, and there is little on what format the colour code should be, so I just assumed RGB as thats what it looks like it should be.

Also looked through the Google Sheets API and that uses RGB.

```
fmt = CellFormat(textFormat=textFormat(bold=True, foregroundColor=color(112, 48, 160), fontSize=24),)
format_cell_range(worksheet, 'B1:B1', fmt)
```

The header should be the same colour as the following RGB code: (112, 48, 160)

Instead of this: (144, 208, 96)

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Comment: Is there anything that I can do for your question? If my answer was not useful for your situation. I have to apologize and modify it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. I would like to think of about the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You want to set the foreground color of a cell of Google Spreadsheet using gspread.

  - You want to set the cell "B1" to the color of `112, 48, 160` which is RGB.
- You want to achieve this using `gspread-formatting`.
- You have already been able to put and get values to the Spreadsheet using gspread.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer?

#### Prepare:

Before you use this modified script, please install `gspread-formatting` as follows. If you have already installed it, please skip this section.

```
$ pip install gspread-formatting
```

#### Modified script:

Please set `spreadsheetId` and `sheetName`.

```
import gspread_formatting as gsf  # <--- Also please add this to your script.

spreadsheetId = "###"
sheetName = "Sheet1"

client = gspread.authorize(credentials)
ss = client.open_by_key(spreadsheetId)
worksheet = ss.worksheet(sheetName)
fmt = gsf.cellFormat(
    textFormat=gsf.textFormat(
        bold=True, foregroundColor=gsf.color(112, 48, 160), fontSize=24)
)
gsf.format_cell_range(worksheet, 'B1:B1', fmt)
```

#### References:

- [gspread-formatting](https://pypi.org/project/gspread-formatting/)

If this was not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Comment: I have found that this also works! Also if you divide your units by 225 you can achieve the same output.

Comment: @Dylan Logan Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The Sheets API wants RGB (and alpha) values to be in the range (0,1); divide each of your typical values by 255.0 and you’ll see the expected results.

#### In the case of the author, the solution for getting the desired rgb values would be:

```py
fmt = CellFormat(textFormat=textFormat(bold=True, foregroundColor=color(112/250, 48/250, 160/250), fontSize=24),)
format_cell_range(worksheet, 'B1:B1', fmt)
```

There are some illustrative examples at
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/formatting

**Source:** https://github.com/robin900/gspread-formatting/issues/7

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).